# Is it correct to say "I have to reschedule the interview for tomorrow night"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am not sure which preposition I should use here, but I have an interview scheduled for/at/on tomorrow's night and I was trying to reschedule it. This is what I wrote:

> Sorry I have not been feeling well since yesterday so I have to reschedule the interview **for** tomorrow night.

Is this correct? How do I let the other person know that I reschedule the interview which was originally scheduled on some date and I want it to be rescheduled at some other date?

Does the sentence I wrote: "I have to reschedule the interview for tomorrow night." mean that:

1. the original interview was scheduled at tomorrow's night
2. Or the newly proposed date is tomorrow's night

Answer (score 1):

The example you give would be taken to mean that you want to reschedule the interview so that it now takes place tomorrow night.

To reschedule a meeting due to take place tomorrow night to some other time you could write:

*Sorry I have not been feeling well since yesterday so I have to reschedule tomorrow night's interview for <some other date/time>.*

Comment: thanks! is it also correct to say "Sorry I have not been feeling well since yesterday so I have to reschedule the interview *at tomorrow's night* for <some other date/time>."?

Comment: _At tomorrow's night_ is not idiomatic English. Just use _tomorrow night_.

Comment: @KateBunting got it. then is it idiomatic to say "Sorry I have not been feeling well since yesterday so I have to reschedule the interview at tomorrow night for <some other date/time>." ？

Comment: Leave out the _at_, as my previous suggestion indicated.

Answer (score 0):

The preposition "for" can refer to the time of a current appointment, or the new time of a rescheduled appointment:

> I have a appointment for 2:00.
> The appointment has been rescheduled for 2:00.

So depending on how the listener parses your sentence, it could have either of the meanings you suggest.

1. I have to reschedule [the interview (which is currently scheduled) for tomorrow night] (to some other time).
2. I have to reschedule [the interview] for (meaning "to") tomorrow night.

To make it unambiguous, you can just remove the "for":

> I have to reschedule *the interview tomorrow night*.

This can only mean that the meeting scheduled for tomorrow night has to be rescheduled to some other time.

Comment: It is ambiguous, but if you have only one interview with the person in question, as is likely the case, it's not a problem.

Comment: @AndrewRay Yes, it wouldn't likely lead to any problems, but to my eye, meaning 2 is the most natural read of that sentence, so it would be best to avoid causing confusion, even if only temporary.

Comment: thanks. but how do you extend this sentence you suggested  "I have to reschedule the interview tomorrow night." to include a newly proposed date and time?

Comment: @Joji You can use "to..." some time.